# Python Office Automation - Moving large amount of files but they are not indexed

Tags: python, windows, search, indexing, shutil

I recently got into the world of automating repetitive tasks using Python.

My recent mini project was resizing several thousand photos in hundreds of folders, then zipping them all and moving to a pre-define folder structure.

All the photos are stored on a network drive so I dragged them all to my computer for faster image resizing and zipping.

My automation code missed a few folders as I was unaware not all the photos were named the same. I wrote a new script to only pull photos from the missing folders on the network drive to my computer. To do the batch resizing, I used a free utility that gives the option of resizing when you right click selected photos in windows explorer. Before I would do a windows search of all .jpgs but for some reason all the new photos I moved with my script were taking forever to show up.

That's when it hit me that when I drag and dropped originally, this also added the files to the index ( I'm using windows 7). Since I used my script, the ~30 000 photos needed to be indexed, and it was going at a snails rate, roughly 6 every 5 seconds.

Is there a way to include have windows index my file moves that I do using Python (os and shutil libraries)?